# Why is SSRS sending report subscriptions that don't exist

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a user receiving an SSRS (SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard) report subscription email, that doesn't seem to exist.

The user receives the expected report at 5 am every morning. However, a few days ago, the user started receiving a blank copy of the same report 2 hours later. I've checked SQL server agent jobs running at that time and verified I do not not have 2 agent jobs running the same report or one agent job running twice. I've checked subscriptions in the reporting database and I don't see a subscription for this user with a 7 am start time.

Can anyone suggest how I can resolve this?

Comment: Please check the SMTP settings for Reporting Services, because at times they keep sending emails if connected to relay server, i had the same issue with email being sent twice in the same day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this was a while ago, but I wanted to give an answer. Turns out the user was receiving forwarded email from another user who recently left the organization. I've worked with my colleagues to speed up the time it takes to deactivate unused email accounts, and send notifications regarding auto delivered reports that should be discontinued.